# parse http response content string

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I am working with javascript in Meteor and I make an HTTP.get request to an API and receive a response  `res = {..., content: "access_token=4h378fi243h085giouf245&expires=5180430", data=null}`. As you can see, `res.content` is a string but it really represent a nice JSON object `{access_token: 4h378fi243h085giouf245, expires: 5180430}`.

Is there a Meteor or Javascript package/easy solution to turn that string into that object?

(I've seen some manual string parsing solutions but that seems hacky, and this seems like something Meteor or Javascript would provide for you.)

EDIT:
Doing JSON.parse(res.content) is actually the first thing I tried but it gives me 'Unexpected token a', I'm guessing from 'access_token'. Why would that not work?

Comment: I do `JSON.parse(res.content)` and it gives me `Unexpected token a`, from 'access_token' I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It actually isn't JSON, it's a URL parameters string.

```
var result = {};
res.content.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
  var item = part.split("=");
  result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
});
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here forget the fact that res.content is not JSON, but is a query string. See this question for how to get the values, with a little tweaking: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

I also created a JavaScript class lib called [Cerealizer](https://github.com/gburghardt/cerealizer) that parses a query string into an object. I'm sure a github search could pull up others as well.

```
var parser = new Cerealizer.QueryString();

res.content = parser.deserialize(res.content);
```

Answer (score -2):

`JSON.parse` should do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mailmindlin: Can you explain this answer better? Why does JSON.parse work here?

Comment: It doesn't work here, which is why this answer is getting down voted